# Building an Irrlicht Game Engine C++ library with CCTools on android device without NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, irrlicht

My question is - is it possible to compile a C++ library that uses some desktop features on mobile device - in this particular case the Irrlicht Engine? I know there is a port out there that uses OGLES drivers, but it also combines using the NDK. I would like to know if there is a possibility to build that library with such a tool like CCTools despite the fact that mobile devices use OpenGL ES - maybe some kind of equivalent libraries, that fit both mobile and desktop environments? There may be some incompatibilities, I know.

The system of input and output doesn't matter at the moment.
And of course - I haven't found the question that fits my expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an article about porting desktop OpenGL apps to Android that might help:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/porting-opengl-games-to-android-on-intel-atom-processors-part-1

I don't see the advantage of using CCTools rather than the NDK.  I think the differences between OpenGL and OpenGL ES would be the biggest problem.

Comment: So it is an issue with low level library function calls, it would be difficult to use with complete engine. It seems that the only solution is using Java/C++ mix with NDK and Irrlicht Port. Anyway, thanks, you made it clear to me.